# cassandra get null data after replace node

Tags: replace, cassandra, null

I have issue with cassandra version 2.1.9.
After replacing node (https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html) we get null data probably until read repair makes data consistent from hints (15-20min).
17 node cluster 150gb+ data on each node, manual repair takes too much time to use it.
We use datastax java driver 3.1.0 for connecting to cluster.
I do not know if it's relevant but we use LeveledCompactionStrategy.
After the replace is done the node is already consistent or the hints need to be loaded?
Any tips how to safely replace node?

Comment: Those steps will give a consistent replacement. It would go into a bootstrapping mode, not accepting reads until it has streamed all the data from a replica so hints/read repairs are not necessary. Are you using quorum for both reads and writes? Are you configuring your driver to connect directly to that node?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, we use consistency level one for both - reads and writes. 
We use disthene with LoadBalancingPolicy TokenLatencyAwarePolicy for that operations (TokenAwarePolicy(LatencyAwarePolicy.builder(new RoundRobinPolicy()).build())). Driver gets list of hosts to connect to.

Comment: if using cl.one its likely to have a delay in consistency. if you need the stronger consistency use (local)quorum instead. but fwiw those steps are a safe replacement.